# Taking an operator from command line and using them as an operator inside the code

Tags: c++, math

I will start with an example

```
me@blabla ./example + 3 5
```

should return 8.

I take the arguments in but how do i convert the "+" from

```
char* opp = argv[1];
```

to a

```
+
```

to use inside my code?

Because I want to use quite a few operators is there a way to do this without using a large if statement?

I hope thats clear, thanks!

Comment: What you want is parsing a math expression - sorry, but that's not going to be trivial.

Answer (score 5):

You will have to have some kind of mapping from the `char` to the operator. Assuming you've already got `3` and `5` in some integer variables `x` and `y`, the simple solution is to use a `switch` statement:

```
switch (opp[0]) {
  case '+': result = x + y; break;
  case '-': result = x - y; break;
  // and so on...
}
```

Alternatively, you could have a `std::map` from `char`s to `std::function<int(const int&,const int&)>`:

```
typedef std::function<int(const int&,const int&)> ArithmeticOperator;
std::map<char, ArithmeticOperator> ops =
  {{'+', std::plus<int>()},
   {'-', std::minus<int>()},
   // and so on...
  };

int result = ops[opp[0]](x,y);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like :

```
char op = argv[1][0];

if (op == '+')
    add(argv[2], argv[3]);
```

Or possibly:

```
switch (op)
{
case '+':
    add(argv[2], argv[3]);
    break;
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test the given operator against a list of operators you'll accept.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc <= 3)
  {
    std::cout << "<op> <num1> <num2>\n";
    return 1;
  }

  const std::string op = argv[1];
  const int arg1 = boost::lexical_cast<int>(argv[2]);
  const int arg2 = boost::lexical_cast<int>(argv[3]);

  cout << arg1 << op << arg2 << " = ";

  if (op == string("+"))    // <== Here is where you turn "+" into +
  {
    cout << arg1 + arg2 << "\n";
  }
  else if (op == string("*"))  // <== or "*" into *
  {
    cout << arg1 * arg2 << "\n";
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "I don't know how to do that yet.\n";
    return 2;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But I would like to use lots of operators ie. *, -, /, % etc.. and not have a large if or switch statement?

Comment: @user1724416 Sooner or later you're going to have some kind of conditional statement. You can't use input as operators in the language.

Answer (score 0):

The most versatile solution for this problem would be to build a parse tree so that you can scale it to a bigger input.

Parse trees are basically binary trees that offer a representation of the relationships between operands and operators, each node up to a leaf is an operator and the leaves themselves are operands so that when you want to analyze or interpret an expression you can start at the bottom of the tree and resolve the expressions as you go up the tree.

The easiest way you can do this is by making a recursive descent parser, you make two stacks, one for operators and one for operands, as you find operators, you push them on the stack along with their respective operands and when you reach an operator with a lower precedence you pop one operator from the stack and operands as needed and you create a node.

If you don't want to go through the hassle of creating your own parser, I've found that boost has some utilities that do that for you. but I have not used them personally, so you'd have to look through the documentation to see if they're of any use. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/libs/spirit/doc/trees.html